# x86 64 AT&T , moving part of register into another register

Tags: indexing, x86, cpu-registers, mov

I'd like to move one byte from register rdx to register rbx, like this:

```
mov %rdx , (%rbx,%r15,1)
```

where 
rdx contains 0x33
,r15 is index and rbx contains 0 at start.

I have tried using this method in many ways , always ending with SIGSEGV error.
In the end I am going to create a rbx register which will contain an array of next rdx values

Comment: You are not moving into a register but into a memory location referenced by rbx and r15. That's the reason for a segfault.

Comment: "rbx register which will contain an array of next rdx values" - that doesn't make any sense, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shift the bytes in one at a time, like this:

```
; Calculate first dl
...
mov  %dl,%bl
; Calculate next dl
...
shlq $8,%rbx
mov  %dl,%bl
; Calculate next dl
...
shlq $8,%rbx
mov  %dl,%bl
```

etc. This assumes that you want the first byte in the msb, and the last byte in the lsb. The revesre order is a bit more complicated, but not much.